# Copy and paste from VS to nano

Tags: visual-studio-code, nano

I have 4 projects for school that written in python. I am required to run the code in bash using nano. Is there is anyway copy and paste from vs code to nano without getting any indentation errors. Like I want the same format as I copy and paste. Because I can't indent 500 lines of code.

Comment: Might be easier to just read from the same file, especially if you're running nano on the same machine as on vs code (plus you can pull your code from version control, such as git).

Comment: I am actually running vocode on windows and my school lab is running on bash. But I never thought I would have encountered any problem like this. So I need to copy from vs code and paste in nano

Comment: How are you connecting from your home pc to your pc in the lab?

Comment: I ssh from my vscode terminal. I just connect to my school server. I also use virtual machine to connect to my school labs. School lab running bash but I use windows machine